# spring boot application-[profile].properties is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I have setup spring boot web project. It works well when I have only one application.properties file with all my database connection details. I am using mysql database. This is my application.properties file.

```
logging.file=myfilename.log
logging.path=/var/log/mydir

# db1
spring.db1.url=jdbc:mysql://[my_host_ip]/db1
spring.db1.username=my_host_username
spring.db1.password=my_host_password
spring.db1.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# db2
spring.db2.url=jdbc:mysql://[my_host_ip]/db2
spring.db2.username=my_host_username
spring.db2.password=my_host_password
spring.db2.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I want to setup different environments e.g. production, dev, test, staging, local.

As per documentation [Profile-specific propertie](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties)

I have created 5 profile specific property files

```
i) application-production.properties

ii) application-dev.properties

iii) application-test.properties 

iv) application-staging.properties

v) application-local.properties
```

I have REMOVED database connection properties from default application.properties file.

I have added this in gradle build to allow passing active profiles

```
bootRun {
    systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

When I bootRun project using gradle

```
./gradlew clean bootRun -Dspring.profiles.active=test
```

It works, it connects to test database.

But in ideal production scenario, I want to **build** the jar file with "test" profile so that it runs all tests and create jar if all tests passes.

e.g.

```
./gradlew clean build -Dspring.profiles.active=test
```

and then deploy jar to different environments (staging, dev, production etc) and run

on dev

```
java -jar myapp.jar  -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

on staging

```
java -jar myapp.jar  -Dspring.profiles.active=staging
```

BUT the build is failing with the exception

```
Caused by:                          org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null
```

Another question is,

Is it possible to just build jar without passing any profile option if I do not have any tests at the beginning ?

```
./gradlew clean build
```

It fails with this exception

```
com.st.ComputeApplicationTests > contextLoads FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException
                    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
                        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException
                            Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException
                                Caused by: java.sql.SQLException
```

**Update:**

As suggested in comments by @Alex,

"ComputeApplicationTests is annotated with @SpringBootTest and doesn't specify any ActiveProfiles. It cannot find appropriate configurations in the default profile and fail"

```
mport org.junit.Test; 
import org.junit.runner.RunWith; 
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest; 
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner; 

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) 
@SpringBootTest 
public class ComputeApplicationTests { 

    @Test 
    public void contextLoads() { 

    } 

}
```

Deleting test make build successful for now.

Comment: Which os are you using? Or try `--spring.profiles.active=<your-profile>` instead of `-D`.

Comment: linux (ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: I posted and deleted my answer, it wasn't clear to me you were talking about a build error. So I guess your "partial stacktrace" is from a unit test ? If you need spring boot context, you need to annotate you test with @SpringBootTest and the appropriate profile

Comment: For testing use `@ActiveProfiles` on your test and make sure that your tests are proper Spring Boot based tests to load the proper config.

Comment: @M. Deinum, Unknown command-line option '--spring.profiles.active'

Comment: What if I havent written any test yet and just want to build my jar using ./gradlew build with test profile option ? Is it mandatory to have atleast 1 test ?

Comment: One of the goal is to have a single build run in all your environments.. So it wouldn't make sense to "build for a target environment". It would only make sense to execute some tests using some specific profile configuration.

Comment: Yes, definately. I want to build jar which should be deployed to different profiles. I dont want to build for target environment. I am passing test profile in build because tests should be part of build. If tests fails, build should succeed.

Comment: But you say you don't have tests yet ? So perhaps you should start by writing a test by following this: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

Comment: Yes I dont have test yet, just setting up things in spring boot. But why is it mandatory to have test to just build ?. I have updated the question to ask to build without passing any profile.

Comment: just build using "gradle build". When you have some test, you'll make it work using the spring boot annotations. 2 separate things.

Comment: To be more precise WHAT is failing... Is it the build? Or is the launching the artifact AFTER the build. Currently it is totally unclear and confusing. Also instead of posting a snippet of a stracktrace put the full stacktrace in your post. Also are you SURE you don't have tests? When using the [initializr](https://start.spring.io) a default one is added.

Comment: That stacktrace clear shows you have a test `ComputeApplicationTests` which probably tries to bootstrap your application.

Comment: @Alex , M. Deinum. Thanks for your help. Having empty test is the issue. Deleting it make build successful.

Comment: After chat discussion: ComputeApplicationTests is annotated with @SpringBootTest and doesn't specify any ActiveProfiles. It cannot find appropriate configurations in the default profile and fails.

Comment: @vishal your last update contains the answer, so you should probably post it as an answer rather than adding it to your question.